# C question from an interview

Tags: c

In What lines will this code fail (meaning: don't do what they are supposed to do), and why?

```
int main(void) {
 char student[64] = "some guy";
 char* teacher;

 /* line1 */ strcpy(teacher, student);
 /* line2 */ teacher=student;
 /* line3 */ strcpy(student, "Alber Einstein");
 /* line4 */ student = teacher;
}
```

Comment: Which lines do you *think* will fail?  Why?  [also: please clarify "fail" -- fail to compile? possibly crash? invoke undefined behavior? hint: all of those are represented]

Comment: Have you [tried compiling it](http://codepad.org/3mNTlit5)?

Comment: Line 3 is wrong, it's Alber*t* Einstein :)

Comment: um, each line will do exactly what its mean't to do. They might be different to what is intended, but without a specification thats not possible to discern.

Comment: "don't [do] what they are supposed to do" is not a useful meaning for "fail" in this context.  Any line in a C program is "supposed" to do what the standard defines it to do, unless it invokes undefined behavior, in which case it is not "supposed" to do anything in particular.

Comment: @Chris: none of the lines will do what they're supposed to do except "line4", which will prevent the program compiling as the standard states that it is supposed to. The rest don't get a chance to *do* anything ;-)

Comment: To be fair, though, in general making reasonable guesses what the programmer probably intended the code to do is a vital programming skill. Calling this intention "what the code was supposed to do" isn't unusual. In this particular case, encountering a tiny program like this with no apparent purpose is rare, and does make it very difficult to make any reasonable guesses. If I came across this code I'd probably just delete it (well, after checking that it's not a negative test case in a compiler test suite)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Line 1 causes undefined behaviour.  Line 4 won't even compile.  Since this seems like it could just as easily be a homework question, and I don't like to give the whole thing away, a quick read of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) or the [C language specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) will explain why.

Comment: line 3 actually has well defined behaviour - the string "Alber Einstein" will be stored into the student buffer

Comment: @Ken - yeah - I read that wrong the first time around.  Now fixed.

Comment: Is #3 ok?  Does "student" in the context mean the same thing as &student[0]?  I thought that was ok... All the others have problems in them though.

Comment: @jmquigley, yes in this case, `student`, `&student`, and `&student[0]` will all end up passing exactly the same value to `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 8):

Sort of in jest, but also serious:

- Line 1 fails because you used the `strcpy( )` function, which may result in the copy overwriting the bounds of the destination buffer if a maintenance programmer increases the size of the `student` array at some point in the future.  This could potentially allow arbitrary code execution in some environments, and is a security vulnerability.
- Line 2 fails because you now have two names for the same block of memory, which may result in aliasing conflicts and data corruption if both are used later.
- Line 3 fails because you have spelled Albert Einstein's name incorrectly.
- Line 4 fails because it's invalid C.

The point is, you need to have a spec before you can have a meaningful discussion about how a program does or does not fail.

Comment: @Steve: right you are!  In my defense, I didn't intend to make a complete list.  (and don't get me started on the missing prototypes, not to mention: who uses single space indenting?).

Comment: good point, nobody has previously said that line 3 is undefined behavior even in C89, because `strcpy` returns `char*` but an unprototyped function is assumed to return `int`.

Answer (score 2):

```
strcpy(teacher, student);
```

This fails because you have not allocated memory using `malloc()` to the teacher. It points to random, and will write to random. `UB` is on the way

Comment: It will not fail.  It will cause runtime pointer error, but you are allowed to do it.  You just write to memory you don't own.  It may crash, it may not.

Comment: @jmq, I used fail to match what his question style.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others have said:
If you're using a C89 compiler, **line 5** "fails" (*)

The function `main` is special only in that it is the function called by the implementation at program startup. Unlike for C99, it is not special in how it terminates. A function with a return type different than `void` **MUST** (in C89 and, except for `main`, in C99) return something to avoid undefined behaviour.

*(*) in C99 there is an implicit `return 0;` right before the closing brace of the function `main`*

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will complain at /* line 4 */. By declaring student in that manner, student will behave like a constant pointer to the starting address of a 64-byte block. It can't be assigned to, though it can be referenced (in lines 1 + 2) and have the memory it points to altered (in line 3).

Comment: The compiler will complain if you are lucky!

Comment: @Carl, you this "Array and pointers aren't the same" is bogus - declaring an array is just a cover-up for building a constant to pointer to a memory block. +1 for dlev

Comment: @Ken: Carl is more correct than you're allowing.  An array is not just a const pointer, even though it decays to a pointer in some circumstances.

Comment: @Ken - declaring an array is not the same as making a pointer.  Check out the C faq linked in my answer if you want to learn more about it.

Answer (score -1):

line 4 will definitely fail, since the declaration `char student[64]` essentially defines `student` to be a constant pointer to a character. The assigment attempts to change the value of the pointer (not the string to which it points), which would violate its constant nature.

line 1 should cause problems at run-time, but will pass the compiler (maybe have a warning generated). Since teach has not been assigned anything (i.e. it is an invalid pointer), you can't copy a value into the location to which it points, since it doesn't really point to anywhere.

Comment: There more similar than you'd like to think. The reason we can assign an array to a pointer-to-char is that an array really does define a pointer to a memory block. The only real difference is that we can do things like sizeof(student) which will return 64 in this case, not 4 like sizeof(teacher) will. Similarly, you are able to write teacher[6] to get the sixth character, because an arrays and pointers are really the same type of thing, so the same rules apply. The dual nature of an array becomes quite clear when using arrays as a function parameter.

Comment: no, an array is not a pointer.  It does 'decay' into a pointer in certain contexts, but they are very much not the same.

Comment: if you declare an `int` variable you can take a pointer to it, it just requires the `&` operator whereas you can get a pointer to the first element of an array without using `&`. Same operation, special syntax for arrays. Does an `int` "really define a pointer to a memory block"? An array *is* a block of memory containing as many objects as you told it to contain. A pointer to it (or some part of it) is just a pointer, it's not the array itself.